# How to change font of reference header into boldface using apacite

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, apa-style, apa6

I am relatively new to latex, most things work however amazingly easily, nevertheless I have a small problem with the the font of the reference header. The start of my code looks like:

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}           
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
```

And at the end of the document I have this:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{References}
```

So as it say, everything works fine, and i get a complete reference list with the correct references, however, the font of the reference header is normal like this:

> References

However as the APA manual dictates is that it should be in boldface like this

> **References**

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mspart}{{\ifapamodeman{\clearpage}{}}\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {\b@level@one@skip}{\e@level@one@skip}%
    {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

I don't know if this is a bug in the `apa6` class, but it might be an oversight on the part of the author if all section headings are supposed to be bold in the APA style.